# Change '//' as comment out in Javascript file Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I want to change "//" in my sublime text 3 to not comment out the following inline text.

I'm using backticks to plug a variable into a URL and Sublime Text is not ignoring the contents, but commenting out the following characters.

Can I make a less-used series of keystokes be my comment out, like "\\" for example? [Here's what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w9av.jpg)

Here is my code in my .js file:

```
function getPhotosForSearch (searchQuery) {
  var url = `${CORS_PROXY}${FLICKR_API_URL}${FLICKR_API_KEY}&text=${searchQuery}`;

  return (
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(res => {
  return res.photos.photo.map(photo => {
    var photoData = {
      large: `https://farm${photo.farm}.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${photo.secret}_b.jpg`,
      thumb: `https://farm${photo.farm}.staticflickr.com/${photo.server}/${photo.id}_${photo.secret}_t.jpg`,
      title: photo.title
    }
    return createFlickrThumb(photoData);
  })
})
)
```

}

Comment: The JavaScript syntax plugin you're using doesn't understand ES2015 string template notation. That's the real problem.

Comment: Have you tried any other editors with more modern JavaScript support, like Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I put the code into a .js file, the highlight worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [**babel-sublime**](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) package.

Quoting from the docs, it supports: *Language definitions for ES6+ JavaScript with React JSX syntax extensions.*

Install with: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, locate: ***Package Control: Install Package***, and select ***Babel***.

Select it in *View* → *Syntax* → *Open all with current extension as...* → *JavaScript (Babel)*

Your code with this environment:

[image]

Comment: @coco_moloko you're welcome. If the answer helped you, feel free to accept it.

Comment: he should have accepted your answer.  did the trick for me, thanks